# Is there a name for X Day of the month?

Tags: usability, gui-design, ux-designer, dates

Im working on a form for a feature for a report that can have its frequency scheduled set by the user. One of the requests from our product owner is that the user is able to set frequency by a monthly option that is "on the third wednesday" of the month. How would this be described in the options?

a On the X day of the month

b "Week of the Month", "Day of the Week" ie. "1st Monday"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at **[Omnifocus](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnifocus)** (a task management app), which has a repeat task option.

They split it into two dropdowns once you select Repeat monthly.

**Option 1: select specific days for the month:**

[image]

**Option 2: select days of the week for each month**

[image]

### Update: Another option - make it read like a sentence

You could also make the form to read like a sentence.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the solution I have presented however it's not the workflow I am looking to solve but its actual name (label). Is there a common name for "on the X day of the month" (ie "on the third wednesday of the month")

Comment: I see...Could you just have a label saying 'on the [select frequency] [select day] of each [month/week]'? You make it read like a sentence so there's no label per se.

Comment: Yeah that could work! I think we're considering integrating the functionality into a label similar to that. Thanks Mike! Big appreciation from Vancouver :)

Comment: np: i've updated my answer with this option